# Storing one user/account's data in a separate database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a client who is requesting to store their data in a separate database. Using multiple databases in Rails 6 seems easy enough, from the standpoint of the logic in my rails code what's a good way to go about this?

I mainly have two tables where if it is the client's data, I would like to be able to store/query from a separate database.

Answer (score 0):

You can just put the details of your second db in database.yml

```
development_sec:
  <<: *default
  database: dn_name
```

Then, you can create a second main model to hold the connection to the db:

```
class ClientRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
    establish_connection :development_sec
    self.abstract_class = true
end
```

After, all your models with the second DB can be inherited from the above main model:

```
class ModelName < ClientRecord
end
```

You can use that in your controller just like you would do it normally.

```
@model = ModelName.all
```